# On DRUPAL 8.5.5 installation

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, development-environment, drupal-8

The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.
Drupal\Core\Config\UnmetDependenciesException: Configuration objects provided by standard have unmet dependencies: block.block.bartik_account_menu (block), block.block.bartik_help (help, block), block.block.bartik_search (search, block), block_content.type.basic (block_content), comment.type.comment (comment), contact.form.feedback (contact), core.entity_form_display.block_content.basic.default (text), core.entity_form_display.node.article.default (image.style.thumbnail, comment, image, path, text), core.entity_form_display.node.page.default (path, text), core.entity_form_display.user.user.default (image.style.thumbnail, image), core.entity_view_display.node.article.default (image.style.large, comment, image, text), core.entity_view_display.node.article.rss (core.entity_view_mode.node.rss), core.entity_view_display.node.article.teaser (core.entity_view_mode.node.teaser, image.style.medium, image, text), core.entity_view_display.node.page.teaser (core.entity_view_mode.node.teaser, text), editor.editor.basic_html (ckeditor, editor), field.field.block_content.basic.body (field.storage.block_content.body, text, field), field.field.comment.comment.comment_body (field.storage.comment.comment_body, text, field), field.field.node.article.body (field.storage.node.body, text, field), field.field.node.article.comment (comment, field), field.field.node.article.field_image (image, field), field.field.node.article.field_tags (field), field.storage.node.comment (comment, node, field), field.storage.node.field_image (file, image, node, field), field.storage.node.field_tags (node, taxonomy, field), field.storage.user.user_picture (file, image, field), filter.format.basic_html (editor, filter), filter.format.restricted_html (filter), node.type.article (node), rdf.mapping.comment.comment (comment, rdf), rdf.mapping.node.article (node, rdf), rdf.mapping.taxonomy_term.tags (taxonomy, rdf), taxonomy.vocabulary.tags (taxonomy) in Drupal\Core\Config\UnmetDependenciesException::create() (line 98 of core\lib\Drupal\Core\Config\UnmetDependenciesException.php).
Drupal\Core\Config\UnmetDependenciesException::create('standard', Array) (Line: 469)
Drupal\Core\Config\ConfigInstaller->checkConfigurationToInstall('module', 'standard') (Line: 132)
Drupal\Core\ProxyClass\Config\ConfigInstaller->checkConfigurationToInstall('module', 'standard') (Line: 145)
Drupal\Core\Extension\ModuleInstaller->install(Array, ) (Line: 83)
Drupal\Core\ProxyClass\Extension\ModuleInstaller->install(Array, ) (Line: 1577)
install_install_profile(Array) (Line: 671)
install_run_task(Array, Array) (Line: 549)
install_run_tasks(Array) (Line: 117)
install_drupal(Object) (Line: 44)

Comment: Add following line in settings.php . ini_set('xdebug.max_nesting_level', 300); i hope it will fixed .

Comment: For more help see this link https://www.drupal.org/node/2613796 , https://www.drupal.org/node/2501851